# Выдаёт ошибку в код

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Извините за столь банальный вопрос

Выдает ошибку:

```
title=Label(frame, f{txts}, bg='#ffffff', font=40)
                    ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Код:

```
import webbrowser as intr
import httplib2 as htp
import time
import keyboard as kb
import os
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title('i am look after you')
root['bg'] = '#ffffff'
root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 1)
root.geometry('720x480')

root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

frame = Frame(root, bg='#ffffff')
frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

txts='Загрузка'
title=Label(frame, f{txts}, bg='#ffffff', font=40)
time.sleep(0.5)
txts='Загрузка.'
time.sleep(0.5)
txts='Загрузка..'
time.sleep(0.5)
txts='Загрузка...'
time.sleep(0.5)
txts='Загрузка'
time.sleep(0.5)
txts='Загрузка.'
time.sleep(0.5)
txts='Загрузка..'
time.sleep(0.5)
txts='Загрузка...'

title.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ваш код неверен не только синтаксически. Он не будет работать так, как вы хотите, даже после исправления ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

правильно будет так:

```
title=Label(frame, txts, bg='#ffffff', font=40)
```

[вот](https://pyneng.github.io/pyneng-6/f-strings/) почитайте о `f` строках

Answer (score -1):

f может использоваться только со строкой.

```
title=Label(frame, f'txts', bg='#ffffff', font=40)
```